# Print only the matched line when process line by line from a file

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have the below code, and its input file "fruits.txt" has following values.

```
Apple
Mango
Grapes
Bananas
Avocado
```

I'm getting the output as below;

```
Grapes not in list
Strawberry not in list
Grapes not in list
Strawberry not in list
Grapes
Strawberry not in list
Grapes not in list
Strawberry not in list
Grapes not in list
Strawberry not in list
Grapes not in list
Strawberry not in list
```

However, i'm actually looking for an output like this, please help!

Expected result as follows.

```
Grapes
Strawberry not in list
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE,"fruits.txt");
    while (<FILE>) {
     if (/Grapes/) {
       print $_;
     } else { print "Grapes not in list\n";}
     if (/strawberry/i) {
       print $_;
     }
     else {
       print "Strawberry not in list\n";
     }
}
close FILE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand why you are getting this output, i.e. why it prints both fruit for every line? Instead of just writing down the answer for you, I'd like to help you understand it yourself. In order to solve this, you will need to use a certain approach that is very simple, but hard to come up with if you've never done this before. You'll facepalm once you see it and then never do it wrong again. :)

Comment: yep, as its process line by line and could not find the match first,second ..and it prints as it find a match in third line ..oh no,..

Comment: it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to have the "not in list" prints inside the loop if you need to have gone through the entire list to know that an item isn't in the list. So let's move them out.

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

open(my $FILE, "<", "fruits.txt")
   or die("Can't open \"fruits.txt\": $!\n");

my $saw_grapes     = 0;
my $saw_strawberry = 0;

while (<$FILE>) {
    ...
}

print "Grapes not in list\n"     if !$saw_grapes;
print "Strawberry not in list\n" if !$saw_strawberry;
```

The rest should now be evident.

```
$saw_grapes     ||= /grapes/i;
$saw_strawberry ||= /strawberry/i;
```

Comment: I find your `||=` a bit hard to understand for a beginner. It's very concise, but not quite idiomatic. I would go with the longer, but more readable `$saw_grapes = 1 if m/grapes/i`.

Comment: @simbabque, You mean `$saw_grapes = 1 if !$saw_grapes && m/grapes/i;`, and that's silly! /// And what's with saying `||=` is not idiomatic? Quite the opposite, you can't even do that in most other languages (except maybe for bool types).

Comment: @simbabque Being "idiomatic" is an interesting concept, no doubt.  Why do you say `||=` isn't? (Just curious. I consider `||=` and its cousins to be just about the most idiomatic thing in Perl.)